# Deleted users showing up in peoplepicker

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, user-profile-service

I have a strange problem in SharePoint 2013 OnPrem.

SP used to be set up with AD import from two domains, let's call them DomainA and DomainB. Then it was decided to remove DomainB, and all users in it. The users of DomainB should no longer have access to SP, and should not appear in people picker controls or otherwise inside SP. What we did so far:

1. Removed the AD import connection to DomainB
2. Removed all the user profiles from DomainB from within Central Admin (manage user profiles)
3. Did a full sync
4. Removed all DomainB users from the user information list (the one at
   /_catalogs/users/simple.aspx) using powershell
5. I even tried setting the Peoplepicker-onlysearchwithinsitecollection
   property using stsadm

But still, the DomainB users are showing up in people picker controls, e.g. when clicking "Share site" and searching for users.

I do not understand where this information is coming from. Any ideas?

Comment: If you run Get-SPUser, do you see them then?

Comment: No, I didn't, so I was quite puzzled until I realized it was a caching issue :)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be just a silly caching issue. After deleting cookies and form data from IE it worked (another guy had to reboot as well).

Before doing that, I also removed the trust to the other domain, so that the people picker could not query that domain directly.

Then I did a db profiling and a fiddler session, just to discover that there was absolutely no trace of the DomainB users in the traffic to the server. That is when it hit me it had to be a caching issue.

It's kind of silly, but to my defence, it was a solution involving several steps, and skipping just one of them would mean failure. It is definitely one of those things that could have been implemented better by MS.